# Как сделать на JavaScript функцию?

Tags: javascript

Люди добрые, помогите, очень нужна помощь. Нужно написать  функцию, которая перебирает целые числа от 0 до бесконечности и выводит на экран, через запятую, те, которые делятся без остатка на количество разрядов (знаков) этого числа (т.е. те двухзначные, которые делятся на 2, трехзначные на три и т.д.). Выполнение обработки должно остановиться в тот момент, когда всего будет выведено N (задается пользователем) таких чисел.

```
   <html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="task">
    <h1>Test</h1>
     <p>Функция, которая перебирает целые числа от 0 до бесконечности и выводит на экран,
    через запятую, те, которые делятся без остатка на количество разрядов (знаков) этого числа 
    (т.е.те двухзначные, которые делятся на 2, трехзначные на три и т.д.).
    Выполнение обработки должно остановиться в тот момент, когда всего будет выведено N (задается пользователем) таких чисел.</p>
     <input type="number" id="cnt" /><input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" onclick="fill();"/>
</div>
</br>
 <div id="inform"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: интересно причем тут приведенный вами хтмл код? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то в таком роде?

```js
var n = prompt('Enter N:'), result = '';

var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; count < n; i++) {
  if (i % i.toString().length == 0) {
    result += i + ', ';
    count++;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее

Comment: @user302628, не за что:)